# In Ruby what does the "receiver" refer to?

Tags: ruby, terminology

I'm reading a document that talks about a method having a receiver. What's a receiver?

Comment: I used to wonder if it was a term inspired by American football.

Comment: The new idea I got from ruby is that OO programming is like a kind of message passing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Ruby (and other languages that take inspiration from SmallTalk) objects are thought of as sending and receiving 'messages'.

In Ruby, Object, the base class of everything, has a send method: [Object.send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send) For example:

```
class Klass
  def hello
    "Hello!"
  end
end
k = Klass.new
k.send :hello     #=> "Hello!"
k.hello           #=> "Hello!"
```

In both of these cases k is the *receiver* of the 'hello' message.

Comment: Is "k.send :hello" actually a syntactically valid way of calling "k.hello" in Ruby?

Comment: You say k is the receiver. So why do we say "k.send :hello" instead of "k.receive :hello"? It *sounds* like k is the sender rather than the receiver.

Comment: Because you're sending TO k, and not receiving TO k.  That latter option makes little sense. ;)

Comment: I am wondering since in Ruby every thing is an object and every function is some method. But in terms of class method `class Hello; def self.say; puts "hello";  end; end` what is the receiver when you call `Hello.say`?  Is `Hello` also an object?

Comment: Yes. `Hello` is truly an object. If you do `Hello.class`, then `Class` will be returned. Thus `Hello` is actually an instance of `Class` class.

Answer (score 8):

In the original Smalltalk terminology, methods on "objects" were instead refered to as messages to objects (i.e. you didn't call a method on object foo, you sent object foo a message). So foo.blah is sending the "blah" message, which the "foo" object is receiving; "foo" is the receiver of "blah".

Answer (score 7):

the object before the .

think of calling a method x.y as saying "send instruction y to object x".

it's the smalltalk way of thinking, it will serve you well as you get to some of Ruby's more advanced features.